# Getting member activity not working in discord.ext

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a discord bot with discord.ext one whose features are returning the primary activity that a user is doing. This is my entire code so far:

```
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import requests



intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$",intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has joined discord!')
    # activity.start()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.content).lower() in ["hello mr. deeds","hey mr.deeds","sup mr. deeds","wassup mr. deeds"]:
        if datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 21:
            await message.channel.send("Hello.")
        elif datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 18:
            await message.channel.send("Hello, good evening.")
        elif datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 12:
            await message.channel.send("Hello, good afternoon.")
        elif datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 6:
            await message.channel.send("Hello, good morning.")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(
    help="Give you motivating and inspiring quotes."
)
async def quote(ctx):
    # SENDS A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL USING THE CONTEXT OBJECT.
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]["q"] + " -" + json_data[0]["a"]
    await ctx.channel.send(quote)

@bot.command(
    help="Give the current activity of the member."
)
async def activity_task(ctx, *args):
    print(ctx.message.mentions[0].activity)


@bot.command(
    help="Announces a message to everyone with a particular role in the server."
)
async def announce(ctx, *args):
    users = ctx.guild.members
    announcement = ""
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == args[0], ctx.message.guild.roles)
    failed_dms= []
    for i in args:
        if i == args[0]:
            continue
        announcement = announcement + " " + i
    for user in users:
        if role in user.roles:
            await bot.get_user(user.id).send(announcement)
        else:
            failed_dms.append(bot.get_user(user.id).name)
    await ctx.channel.send("Announcement sent successfully.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I set my gaming activity as chrome, vs code or even actual games and it just keeps returning `None`. Where is the error? I have also enabled all the settings in the developer portal.